# Using StringExpression in a string list

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation

I'm trying to search in a list of strings those who match a pattern. But it seems that `StringExpression` in functions such as `Position` or `Case` won't work as in `StringCase`.

```
Cases[{"ABC", "DEF"}, StringExpression["DE", _]]
```

> {}

```
StringCases["ABC DEF", StringExpression["DE", _]]
```

> {DEF}

Why this happens?

Comment: `Cases[{"ABC", "DEF"}, _String?(StringMatchQ[StringExpression["DE", _]])]` or `Cases[{"ABC", "DEF"}, _?(StringMatchQ[StringExpression["DE", _]])]` ?

Comment: Documentation for `StringExpression` states: `StringExpression objects can be used in many string manipulation functions, including StringReplace, StringCases, StringSplit, and StringMatchQ.`. If you want to use it in other functions, use `StringMatchQ` with `StringExpression` as @kglr commented.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why this happens?

Because `Cases` expects an expression pattern and `StringCases` expects a string pattern.

With `Case`, write an expression pattern that invokes the string pattern matcher explicitly. Or better: use `Select`.

```
Select[{"ABC", "DEF"}, StringMatchQ["DE" ~~ _]]
(* {"DEF"} *)

Cases[{"ABC", "DEF"}, s_ /; StringMatchQ[s, "DE" ~~ _]]
(* {"DEF"} *)
```

See [`Select`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Select.html), [`Cases`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cases.html), [`StringMatchQ`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringMatchQ.html).